# Modal pop up calendar control issue

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using a Calendar extender in a modalpopup when i click the image button the calendar extender should be displayed and when i click a particular date that date should be displayed in the textbox its working but what my problem is when i click the image button for the first time the calendar extender is displayed in the back side of the modal pop hence i am unable to select a particular date. but when i click the same image button for the second time the calendar extender will be displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in head section of the page

```
<style type="text/css"> 
   .ajax__calendar_container { z-index : 1000; } 

</style>
```

Note:Please change the value of z-index accordingly.

Comment: @ geeks thanks for replying but still it is not showing on the first time

Comment: <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" PopupPosition="BottomLeft" runat="server" TargetControlID="textbox1" PopupButtonID="btnCal" CssClass="ajax__calendar_container" Enabled="true">                                   </asp:CalendarExtender>

Answer (score 0):

```
//use java script
function calendarShown(sender, args)
{
    sender._popupBehavior._element.style.zIndex = 10005;
}
```